# What getActionEl( ) in extjs4 actually returns?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS4 there is a new `getActionEl( )` function for Ext.Component.

There is no documentation for it.

What the function returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns the `el` of the instance from which you call it. But it is private and it is already deprecated so I wouldn't use it.